# Sort by variables in dropdown from php variables

Tags: javascript, php

I have a dropdown/sort select list with 2 options `Popularity and Recently Ordered`.

I want to filter objects on the page by these attributes and I want to connect the two options in my select to respective functions in my dataloader.php file.

The functions are below but I want to connect `$ofpg->reorder` to recently ordered and `$ofpg->topseller` to popularity, but I'm not sure how exactly to load these to my select box and attach JS to sort by. Basically I just want to use JS to reorder the items on the page by these items, but I need some guidance to get started.

Here's the code:

My dropdown/sort by:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
   <div>
    <span style="color:#fff;"><strong>Sort by:</strong></span>
    <select class="uk-text-muted" style="margin-top:10px; width:33%; height:30px; font-size: 16px;" >
    <option class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 16px;" value="" selected data-default>Popularity</option>
    <option class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 16px;" value="">Recently Ordered</option>
    </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Top seller and recent order functions:

```
$ofpg = new OfDataProductGroup();
        $ofpg->group_code = trim($group['groupCode']);
        $ofpg->group_name = $group['groupName'];
        $ofpg->group_desc = $group['webDsc'];
        $ofpg->ctg = $group['ctg'];

        $ofpg->topseller = 0;
        $ofpg->reorder = 0;

        if($this->reorder){
            foreach($this->reorder as $i){

                if(trim($group['groupCode']) == $i->STYLE){
                    $ofpg->reorder = 1;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        if($this->topsellers){

            foreach($this->topsellers as $i){
                $aa = json_decode($i->metadata);
                $s = $aa->style[0]->prdgroup;
                if(trim($group['groupCode']) == $s){
                    $ofpg->topseller = 1;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you give me some context of how to use that? I'm wondering how to not only attach those variables to the select but also how I would incorporate JS to add functionality

Comment: @RonnieOosting I basically want the JS to just say ```if 'popularity' is selected and $ofpg->popularity == true then show those products first``` or something along those lines

Comment: I think so but would that all be done in the JS? So I'd leave the select box the way it is, and do the 'if' statement in JS?

Comment: Ok I see, I'll try that then, thanks!

Comment: Yes it did, I just have to sort things out in my function but the drop down does exactly what it should. If you will write an answer I'll gladly accept and vote it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that might work is using an `if` statement and put `continue;` within it on the top of your `foreach`.

Something like:

```
foreach($aa as $a)
{
   if($a != $something) // or use ($a == $something), just whatever you need.
   {
      continue;
   }

echo $a;
}
```

In the situation above you use a `foreach` to do something with every key from your array. But on top of this `foreach` you have an `if` statement. The `if` statement will only show the result if it matches the requirement, otherwise it will do nothing and continues to the next key.

**EDIT:**
This is written in `PHP`, not in `JS`.